# How to do a Linq Left Outer Join with a middle table?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I've been following a few examples from this website on how to create Linq Left Outer Join queries but I haven't found any examples of where the "outer key in the left join doesn't point to the inner key but instead points to a previous key". Bear with me for that phrasing I know it's not correct but have a look at the following snippets of code and maybe it will be clearer.

Specifically, see the first left join where sp.SalesPersonID = j.SalesPersonID.

```
select rt.Name as ResourceType, s.FirstName + ' ' + s.Surname as Supervisor, sp.FirstName + ' ' + sp.LastName as SalesPerson, tr.OrderCodeID, tr.SkillID
    , j.CustomerName, j.JobNumber
from dbo.TaskResource tr join projects.Task t on t.ID = tr.taskiD
    join dbo.ResourceType rt on rt.ID = tr.ResourceTypeID
    join projects.projecttask pt on pt.taskid = tr.taskid 
    join projects.jobproject jp on jp.projectid = pt.projectid 
    join crm.tbljobs j on j.jobid = jp.jobid 
    left join common.tblSalesPersons sp on sp.SalesPersonID = j.SalesPersonID
    left join common.tblSupervisors s on s.SupervisorID = j.SupervisorID
where JobDeleted is null or JobDeleted = 0
order by ResourceType
```

When converted to Linq it would make

```
...from j in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join sp in dbc.tblSalesPersons on j.SalesPersonID equals sp.SalesPersonID into temp2
```

So far so good. But when I do the next left join I though it would just be the same thing but *pointing to one of the previous keys* as I mentioned earlier so instead of using the **sp** variable which I've seen several examples of, I use the **j** variable which is from a previous join:

```
from sp in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in dbc.tblSupervisors on j.SupervisorID equals s.SupervisorID
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```
List<ResourceTreeObject> resourceTreeObjects = (
                from tr in dbc.TaskResources
                join t in dbc.Tasks on tr.TaskID equals t.ID
                join rt in dbc.ResourceTypes on tr.ResourceTypeID equals rt.ID
                join pt in dbc.ProjectTasks on tr.TaskID equals pt.TaskID
                join jp in dbc.JobProjects on pt.ProjectID equals jp.ProjectID
                join j in dbc.tblJobs on jp.JobID equals j.JobID into temp1
                from j in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join sp in dbc.tblSalesPersons on j.SalesPersonID equals sp.SalesPersonID into temp2
                from sp in temp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join s in dbc.tblSupervisors on j.SupervisorID equals s.SupervisorID
                where j.JobDeleted == null || j.JobDeleted == 0
                select new ResourceTreeObject
                {
                    TaskResourceID = tr.ID
                    ,
                    TaskID = tr.TaskID
                    ,
                    ResourceTypeID = tr.ResourceTypeID
                    ,
                    ResourceType = rt.Name
                    ,
                    SkillID = tr.SkillID
                    ,
                    OrderCodeID = tr.OrderCodeID
                    ,
                    PermissionID = tr.PermissionID
                    ,
                    JobID = j.JobID
                    ,
                    JobNumber = j.JobNumber
                    ,
                    CustomerName = j.CustomerName
                    ,
                    Salesperson = sp.FirstName + " "  + sp.LastName
                    ,
                    Supervisor = s.FirstName + " " + s.Surname

                }).ToList();
```

And this results in the wrong query. The last "left join" is treated like an inner join and returns the wrong number of rows. So in essence what I'm asking is, how do I (in LinQ) do two consecutive left outer joins after doing several consecutive inner joins but use the key from one of the previous tables in my left out join?

Also I'm not sure what the correct terminology for inner/outer keys etc. hence the awkward phrasing and title. Perhaps someone could correct that so it would be more beneficial to others. Thank you.

Comment: how about creating the left outer join like this **ex:** `from sp in dbc.tblSalesPersons.Where(w=>w.SalesPersonID == temp1.SalesPersonID).DefaultIfEmpty()`. For more info on it check [Left outer join Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558389/2417602).

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. I pasted it after the **join j** line and commented the subsequent 3 lines but temp1 didn't have a reference to SalesPersonID at that point. I'll check out the link maybe there's something there.

Comment: Check out my answer to resolve that issue.  Once that's working, you can change to the other syntax if you prefer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ translation is just a little off.

The SQL has an inner join on `crm.tbljobs` followed by outer joins on `common.tblSalesPerson` and `common.tblSupervisors`.

The LINQ has outer joins on `dbc.tblJobs` and `dbc.tblSalesPersons` followed by an inner join on `dbc.tblSupervisors`.

`into temp1` ... `from j in in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()` makes the outer join happen on the table introduced prior to the `into`, which is `dbc.tblJobs`.

So it should be:

```
...
// inner join
join j in dbc.tblJobs on jp.JobID equals j.JobID

// left outer join
join sp in dbc.tblSalesPersons on j.SalesPersonID equals sp.SalesPersonID into salesPersons
from sp in salesPersons.DefaultIfEmpty()

// left outer join
join s in dbc.tblSupervisors on j.SupervisorID equals s.SupervisorID into supervisors
from s in supervisors.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

I changed `temp1` and `temp2` to more meaningful names to demonstrate what they represent in the outer join syntax.  Note the relationship and relative position of `dbc.tblSalesPersons` to `salesPersons`, for example.

One more thing to remember is that `sp` and `s` can be null, so make sure you check for that before accessing their `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `Surname` properties.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I knew it was a small tweak required at the end there. Yes I wanted two outer joins at the end but mistakenly put it for tblJobs. I see, so it was the same pattern just in the wrong place. And thanks for null checking comment that's true as well.

Comment: Glad I could help.